# How to write an inputText accepting only integers in the #,###.00 pattern

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any way of writing an inputText which is only accepting digits and also in the #,###.00 pattern format for inputting a currency number in JSF ? (using PrimeFaces will be more appreciated)

Thanks...

Comment: Hi FailedDev, I am new to JSF and don't know the Regex. Could you tell a little bit about the Regex? How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Check this [link](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/masked-input-for-jsf/)

Here says you can use:

```
<p:inputMask value="# {maskController.date}" mask="99/99/9999"/>
```

I never used PrimeFaces before but i've used JSF. If you dont want to use javascript, you need to use a convert tag inside of the inputText tag.

```
<h:inputText id="money" required="true">
<f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"
    groupingUsed="true"
    currencySymbol="$"
    maxIntegerDigits="4"
    type="currency"/>
</h:inputText>
```

PD: RegEx is another option. RegEx means Regular Expression. It is a way to check if something like an string matches with a rule. You can use in jsf with the RegEx Validator.

Answer (score 1):

This below code is working

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function isNumber(event) {
  if (event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) 
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
]]>
</script>

<p:inputText id="money" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" />
```

to erase key available

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function isNumber(event) {
  if (event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&  charCode!=8 && charCode!=46) 
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
]]>
</script>

<p:inputText id="money" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" />
```

Comment: This is great but it doesn't allow to process the erase key properly

Comment: to erase key edit

if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&  charCode!=8 && charCode!=46)

Answer (score 1):

Adding additional helpful not listed answer for this question :

Simply you can use primefaces extension tag `inputNumber` : 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml